# Automatic display selection

Tags: windows-xp, display

I'm running Windows XP Professional on my laptop. When I come home and connect to an external display, I have to switch to it manually. Is there a way to select the external display automatically if it is present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me on my laptop with Windows XP (using a Mobile Intel 965 Express chipset with integrated graphic card). When I connect the laptop to an external monitor, this monitor becomes the primary and the laptop screen becomes secondary.

I suggest you update the graphic card drivers, as it's a feature managed by the drivers. It used not to work correctly for me until an updated driver came out.

Otherwise, you could have more luck with the Profiles feature of [**Ultramon**](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/display_profiles.asp).

Answer (score 0):

A docking station could do this if your laptop supports one.